# Django celery WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL) error

Tags: django, celery, virtualenv, production-environment

What is the best practice to run celery as a daemon in a production virtualenv? I use the following in the local environment which works perfect and receiving tasks works as expected. But in production always stuck at

```
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL) error
```

I use the following configuration in local and in production:

**/etc/default/celeryd:**

```
CELERY_BIN="path/to/celery/bin"
CELERY_APP="myproj"
CELERYD_CHDIR="home/myuser/project/myproj"
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=4"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_USER="myuser"
CELERYD_GROUP="myuser"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

**/etc/init.d/celeryd:**[[celeryd](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd)]

**Package & OS version info:**

1. Ubuntu == 16.04.2
2. Celery == 4.1.0
3. rabbitmq == 3.5.7
4. django == 2.0.1

I also use these commands while making celery to run as daemon:

1. sudo chown -R root:root /var/log/celery/
2. sudo chown -R root:root /var/run/celery/
3. sudo update-rc.d celeryd defaults
4. sudo update-rc.d celeryd enable
5. sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start

Here is my django **settings.py** configuration for celery:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///results.sqlite'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Need expert advise to make the celery daemon to work correctly in production virtualenv.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error due to out of memory error caught in

> /var/log/kern.log

I have Tensorflow running in one of my tasks, which needs additional computational power, but my physical memory(RAM) is not sufficient to handle that much load. I weird that there's no log in celery except SigKill 9 error. But the kernel log helped me to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've created a seperate vhost & user for rabbitmq, set the CELERY_BROKER_URL to `amqp://guest@localhost//`

Also, rather than root, you should set the owner of `/var/log/celery/` and `/var/run/celery/` to "myuser" as you have set in your celeryd config

Comment: In local environment I use CELERY_BROKER_URL="amqp://localhost" in production I need to use as amqp://guest@localhost/ right?

Comment: It will depend on how you've configured rabbitmq. If that works locally, then I suspect that it is purely down to the permissions on the file system

Answer (score 1):

I guess this can be a symptom of OOM. I was deploying a Celery backend in a Docker container - "it worked on my machine" but not in the cluster. I allocated more ram to the task and no longer have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case of docker, I just allocated more resources and it worked.

[image]